# WPF - Checkbox bound to whether or not ObservableCollection contains a value?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I currently have a checkbox that is bound to a property that checks an ObservableCollection for a specific value.  If the value exists, then the property returns true.

My property and the property that exposes the ObservableCollection are both readonly.

This approach works fine when I first load my model, but when it add additional items into the ObservableCollection the checkbox that is bound to the property does not update.

Here's the code for my property:

```
public bool IsMeasure11
{
    get //readonly
    {
       return this.Charges.Any(t => t.IsMeasure11);
    }
}
```

And here's the code for my ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<DACharge> Charges
{
    get //readonly
    {
        if (_charges == null)
        {
             _charges = new GenericEntityCollection<DACharge>(_DACase.Id).ToList().ToObservableCollection();
        }

        return _charges;
    }
}
```

And the XAML for the Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Content="M11" Name="chkM11" IsChecked="{Binding IsMeasure11, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property does not implment [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) so there is no way for the binding engine to know to update the bound property.

An `ObservableCollection<T>` does not update the property which it is being returned within; in this instance the `public ObservableCollection<DACharge> Charges` property.

You will need to register for the [ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event and when an item is added/removed, etc...fire a `PropertyChanged` event as displayed in the previous link for the `Charges` property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate the binding of IsMeasure11 (i.e. invoke the PropertyChanged event of INotifyPropertyChanged) whenever the Charges collection changes.  One way of doing this would be to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the Charges collection.

```
// somewhere, maybe the constructor of your view model
this.Charges.CollectionChanged += ChargesChanged;

private void ChargesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  this.NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => IsMeasure11);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your "add item" action to fire up the INotifyChanged Interface's PropertyChanged event as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

If not then WPF will never know when the value changes as the binding isnt sourced at the ObservableCollection but to another property that accesses it instead.

Hope it helps.